# How to unregister the broadcast receiver in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Is it necessary to unregister the broad cast receiver? If so then how can I unregister it.
My code scenario is as follows:

I have make a static method to send an sms in which I have registered a broadcast receiver like that:

```
    public static void sendSMS(final Context mContext,String phoneNumber, String message)
    {
        String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
        String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0,
            new Intent(SENT), 0);

        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0,
            new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

        //---when the SMS has been sent---
        mContext.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "SMS sent", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Generic failure", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "No cellular network service Available", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Null PDU", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Radio off", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

        //---when the SMS has been delivered---
        mContext.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "SMS delivered", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "SMS not delivered", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;                        
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));        



        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);        
    }
```

This method is created in a non activity class whose name is HomeSafeStaticMethod. Now what I do I am calling this method in my service to send the sms like that:-

```
HomeSafeStaticMethod.sendSMS(CheckInSOSMessageService.this,emergencyNumber,first_Name+"\n"+address+"  "+city+"  "+country);
```

This method is calling from onCreate method of my service class. Now I want that when my service will finished I want to unregister the broad cast receiver in onDestroy method.How can I achieve that... Please help me to sort out this problem.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call
[unregisterReceiver (BroadcastReceiver receiver)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#unregisterReceiver%28android.content.BroadcastReceiver%29) to unregister the broadcast receivers. The context you have received as part of `sendSMS` should be stored and then later the same can be used to unregister the receiver.

**EDIT:**

```
private static Context mContext = null;

static BroadcastReceiver mSentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        switch (getResultCode()) {
        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "SMS sent", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Generic failure", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "No cellular network service Available", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Null PDU", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Radio off", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }
    }

};

static BroadcastReceiver mDeleiveredReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        switch (getResultCode()) {
        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "SMS delivered", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "SMS not delivered", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;                        
        }
    }
};

public static void sendSMS(final Context context,String phoneNumber, String message) {
    if(mContext == null) {
        mContext = context;
        mContext.registerReceiver(mSentReceiver, new IntentFilter(SENT));
        mContext.registerReceiver(mDeleiveredReceiver, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));
    }

    // rest of your code ....
}

// this method should be called whenever you want to remove the receivers
public static void removeReceivers() {
    mContext.unregisterReceiver(mSentReceiver);
    mContext.unregisterReceiver(mDeleiveredReceiver);
    mContext = null;
}
```

Comment: Okay Rajeev..I got your point.Let me implement it in my project. Thanks

Comment: hey Rajiv thanks a lot bro..Its working now absolutely fine.. :)

Comment: as per the question, **This method is created in a non activity class whose name is HomeSafeStaticMethod.**, and also **This method is calling from onCreate method of my service class.**

Answer (score 0):

Just write the following code

```
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(this, BroadCastReceiverClass.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT).cancel();
```